# Global Object using extern in header file

Tags: c++, global, extern

I want to have a global instance of a Class I have made in my program.
Right now,I can do the same thing with integers,floats,or Classes I imported from libraries(e.g Qt).
Here is my structure

File:Common.h

```
#ifndef COMMON_H
#define COMMON_H
#include "CChess.h"
extern CChess game;
#endif
```

File:TestGame.cpp

```
#include "common.h"
#include "CChess.h"
CChess game;
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
   //main code
}
```

File:CChess.h

```
#ifndef CCHESS_H
#define CCHESS_H


#include "Common.h"
#include "CBoard.h"

class CChess
{
public:
    CBoard mqGameBoard;
    PinchState current_hand_state;
    char mcPlayerTurn;

    //constructors
    CChess();
    ~CChess() {}
    //methods
    void setPinchState(PinchState current_hand_state);
    PinchState getPinchState();
    void Start();
    void GetNextMove(CPiece* qpaaBoard[8][8]) ;
    void AlternateTurn();
};

#endif
```

I get:

```
Error   75  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'game'    .\Common.h  
Error   76  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   .\Common.h  93
```

What can I do?
Exactly the same thing works perfectly with int,float etc

Comment: And how does the header-file `CChess.h` look like? You haven't forgot a semicolon there?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg *spectacular* second question.  You win the crystal ball award.

Comment: I just added it in the question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the circular dependency you have with your include files: `Common.h` needs `CChess.h` which needs `Common.h` and so on.

You need to break this circle somehow, like not including `Common.h` in `CChess.h`, as it doesn't seem to be needed there.

Comment: Hmm right now It seems to be needed(you can't see it but CChess.cpp uses a variable which is declared extern in Common.h. Any alternatives you  could suggest?

Comment: @mbiks Avoiding global variables (which is a good advice in general)? Use pointers instead of non-pointer values (then only class declarations are needed and not the full class definition)?

Comment: Can't avoid globals, because I work with OpenGL so variables between Render,Idle and main has to be seen by all 3